# SVG rasterization issue in a QML Canvas

Tags: qt, canvas, svg, qml

I am experiencing issues when using the QML Canvas [drawImage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#drawImage-method-1) method to render SVG icons.
Basically the QML Canvas ignores the rasterization size and paint the image starting from its original size (in this case 48x48px), and scaling it up with an ugly aliasing effect.

Has anyone ever seen this and possibly figured out a solution ?

Please see [QTBUG-59878](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59878) for a working self-contained example.
Here I'm gonna copy just the QML code and a screenshot of what I see.

[image]

From the left:

- the original SVG icon as Image item (correct)
- the same Image item rendered by drawImage (to be honest I expected this to be correct as well, since rasterized data should be provided by Image)
- the SVG icon loaded with the procedure explained in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-canvas-example.html), with loadImage and onImageLoaded

import QtQuick 2.0

```
Rectangle
{
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Image
    {
        id: svgIcon
        source: "qrc:/qt_logo.svg"
        x: 10
        y: 100
        width: 180
        height: 200
        sourceSize: Qt.size(width, height)
    }

    Canvas
    {
        id: canvas
        anchors.fill: parent
        contextType: "2d"
        property string imagefile: "qrc:/qt_logo.svg"

        Component.onCompleted: context.loadImage(imagefile)

        onImageLoaded: requestPaint()

        onPaint:
        {
            context.drawImage(svgIcon, 200, 100, 180, 200)
            context.drawImage(imagefile, 400, 100, 180, 200)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with SVG within QML, the performance is very poor and quality of upscaling and downscaling isn't good enough. if you're using SVG for showing icons, i will suggest you to use fonts instead of svg icons, its pretty fast and high quality. you can convert your svg icons to font characters, and pack them in single font and use it within QML as Text or label elements, seen [Iconmoon.io](https://icomoon.io/)

Comment: I already use FontAwesome for several other icons, but I need SVG too. Moreover, fonts are monochromatic.